# Parent Model that can only have one child in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Sorry the title is pretty unclear - I'm just not quiet sure how to phrase the question without explaining it.

I would like to record workouts with my app. I would like a Workout Table (what I'm calling the parent) that has basic information like date and sub_workout_type_id

A workout record can have either a Cardiovascular workout (One Model) or a Strength Workout (Another Model).

My thought on have 3 tables instead of just the 2 Cario Workout model and strength workout model is that I would be able to pull a feed of any type of workout, by pulling the Workout Records and then dig deeper as needed.

Perhaps there is a more ruby-ish way to do this? Because right now I don't know of a way to say has_one_model_or_the_other. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options, either you use STI (single table inheritance) : in that case you would have a single table that would be able to contain both a cardiovascular model or a strength workout, and a type. This would only work if the two models share some common characteristics.

Another solution is to write something like

```
has_one :cardiovascular
has_one :strength
```

and then use validations to enforce that only one of them is set.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I love the idea of using STI - I had no idea this was available. One question I have is about performance. Let's say cario has 25 fields and strength has 25 - would you foresee the queries taking longer or being less efficient in one table? Also, can I write migrations for each type like I would a normal model? Or do can I only write migrations for the Workout? Sorry for 2 questions in 1 comment!

Comment: The efficiency difference probably wouldn't be noticeable, but it'd be easy enough to find out some real-world numbers. Migrations aren't model-specific--any migration can contain any info, for any table, for multiple tables, etc.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton for clearing that up. I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @nathanvda, STI could be a good choice.

If you're looking to store class specific data with your models, maybe check out [Modeling inheritance with Ruby/Rails ORMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216215/modeling-inheritance-with-ruby-rails-orms/7216559#7216559) to see if that answer gives you any ideas on how to model this relationship.

Note, the example there uses `has_many`'s but a lot of the ideas are similar.